# Can I get Xeon E5-2630v2 working on proliant DL160 Gen8?

Tags: hp-proliant, xeon

I'm replacing my 2xE5-2620 with 2xE5-2630v2, however after switching the CPUs the server doesn't start (doesn't wake the screen, no beep after a few min) and the status indicator blinks red.

System ROM: J03 05/24/2019

Have I missed something, shouldn't this work for some reason or are both CPUs from ebay broken?
Would buying a usb-cable for the serial-port help me debug this?

Comment: read the manual, there, is a compatibility list which is generated by the vendor

Comment: That works with the Dell Precision but not the HP Proliant DL series.  

It is a function of the BIOS. 

Try upgrading the BIOS using one older but original CPU during the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It depends.

The DL160 Gen8 system board comes in two variants, 677046-001 and 740979-001.
677046-001 cannot be updated to support Ivy Bridge, and 740979-001 supports Ivy Bridge out of the box.

It is unclear what the difference between these two boards is and why a System ROM upgrade of 677046-001 is not enough.